# Change positions for x variables in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

this is my plot:

[image: plot]

As you can see, the x variables are very close with each other and the representation is misleading, for it seems that the variable "Gloria*" has data, but in fact all the variables with the asterisk should be empty. Is there any way to add more space between them? Maybe by moving them closer to the axes' intersection?

Here's my plot's code:

```
    \definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}
\definecolor{pinky}{HTML}{ff66ff}
\definecolor{greeny}{HTML}{99ffcc}
\definecolor{bluy}{HTML}{6699ff}
\definecolor{orangy}{HTML}{ffd966}
\definecolor{verdino}{HTML}{d9ff66}
\definecolor{rossino}{HTML}{ff6666}
\definecolor{celestino}{HTML}{66ffff}
\definecolor{arancino}{HTML}{ff8c66}
\definecolor{giallino}{HTML}{ffff66}
\definecolor{violetto}{HTML}{bf00ff}
\definecolor{rosino}{HTML}{ffcccc}
\definecolor{violazzo}{HTML}{eee6ff}
\definecolor{bluone}{HTML}{4400cc}
\definecolor{grigino}{HTML}{b3b3b3}
\definecolor{verdastro}{HTML}{009900}
\definecolor{verdillino}{HTML}{ccffcc}
\definecolor{nerino}{HTML}{003300}
\definecolor{gialligno}{HTML}{ffff00}
\definecolor{violello}{HTML}{ff0080}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=4pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Frequency},
        symbolic x coords={Ed$\ast$,Amy$\ast$,Frank$\ast$,Gloria$\ast$,Gia,April},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                legend columns=7,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,1)(April,21)}; %go

        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,13)(April,19)}; %want

        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,2)}; %keep

        \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]  coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,3)(April,18)}; %can

        \addplot[style={pinky,fill=pinky,mark=none}] coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %be

        \addplot[style={greeny,fill=greeny,mark=none}] coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %forget
             
        \addplot[style={bluy,fill=bluy,mark=none}] coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,2)}; %think

        \addplot[style={orangy,fill=orangy,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %must

        \addplot[style={verdino,fill=verdino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %see

        \addplot[style={rossino,fill=rossino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,5)}; %get

        \addplot[style={celestino,fill=celestino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %need

        \addplot[style={arancino,fill=arancino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %hafta

        \addplot[style={violetto,fill=violetto,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,0)(April,1)}; %hear
             
        \legend{go,want,keep,can,be,forget,think,must,see,get,need,hafta,hear}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distances between ticks are to small. Try to enlarge it, for example by defined `x` size:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}
\definecolor{pinky}{HTML}{ff66ff}
\definecolor{greeny}{HTML}{99ffcc}
\definecolor{bluy}{HTML}{6699ff}
\definecolor{orangy}{HTML}{ffd966}
\definecolor{verdino}{HTML}{d9ff66}
\definecolor{rossino}{HTML}{ff6666}
\definecolor{celestino}{HTML}{66ffff}
\definecolor{arancino}{HTML}{ff8c66}
\definecolor{giallino}{HTML}{ffff66}
\definecolor{violetto}{HTML}{bf00ff}
\definecolor{rosino}{HTML}{ffcccc}
\definecolor{violazzo}{HTML}{eee6ff}
\definecolor{bluone}{HTML}{4400cc}
\definecolor{grigino}{HTML}{b3b3b3}
\definecolor{verdastro}{HTML}{009900}
\definecolor{verdillino}{HTML}{ccffcc}
\definecolor{nerino}{HTML}{003300}
\definecolor{gialligno}{HTML}{ffff00}
\definecolor{violello}{HTML}{ff0080}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
%        height = 8cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
x=24mm,           % <-----
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=4pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Frequency},
        symbolic x coords={Ed$\ast$,Amy$\ast$,Frank$\ast$,Gloria$\ast$,Gia,April},
        xtick = data,
%        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.1, % <--- changed
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={at={(1,1.05)},
                        anchor=south east,
                        legend columns=7,
                        column sep=1ex
                    }
            ]
\addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,1)(April,21)}; %go

\addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,13)(April,19)}; %want
\addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,2)}; %keep
\addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]  
            coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,0)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,3)(April,18)}; %can
\addplot[style={pinky,fill=pinky,mark=none}] 
            coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %be
\addplot[style={greeny,fill=greeny,mark=none}] 
            coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %forget
\addplot[style={bluy,fill=bluy,mark=none}] 
            coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,2)}; %think
\addplot[style={orangy,fill=orangy,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %must
\addplot[style={verdino,fill=verdino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %see
\addplot[style={rossino,fill=rossino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,5)}; %get
\addplot[style={celestino,fill=celestino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %need

\addplot[style={arancino,fill=arancino,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %hafta
\addplot[style={violetto,fill=violetto,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(Ed$\ast$,1)(Amy$\ast$,0)(Frank$\ast$,0)(Gloria$\ast$,0)(Gia,2)(April,1)}; %hear
\legend{go,want,keep,can,be,forget,think,must,see,get,need,hafta,hear}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE are changed some y bar values that they are better visible.

[image]